# Como somar +x a cada registro retornado em um SELECT

Tags: php, sql, query, mysqli

Por exemplo, em um `select` no banco, serão retornados 5 registros:

```
SELECT * FROM esc_usuarios
WHERE usu_indicador_codigo = '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "'
AND usu_situacao = 'ativo'"
```

Depois quero atribuir um valor para cada registro, por exemplo 10. Agora quero dar um `echo` na soma do valor de todos esses registros, ou seja, 5 (registros do select) x 10 (valor atribuído para cada registro), me retornando então o número 50. Como posso fazer isso?

**Update 0:**
Nova query

```
SELECT usu_nome, (
          (SELECT (count(usu_codigo)*10) FROM esc_usuarios WHERE usu_indicador_codigo = a.usu_codigo AND usu_situacao = 'ativo')
          +
          (SELECT (count(usu_codigo)*5) FROM esc_usuarios WHERE usu_indicador_codigo in (
            (SELECT usu_codigo FROM esc_usuarios WHERE usu_indicador_codigo = a.usu_codigo AND usu_situacao = 'ativo')
          ))
        ) usu_porcentagem
        FROM esc_usuarios a
        WHERE usu_codigo = 1
```

Comment: Olá amigo, seja bem vindo. Vamos lá, poderia detalhar melhor como gostaria de atribuir este número 10 a cada linha retornada? seria uma coluna em especifico da tabela consultada ou seria uma variável dentro do loop em que se consulta as linhas no php? pois até o momento penso que daria para resolver tudo dentro do proprio select... tente detalhar melhor seu objetivo e a situação por favor.

Comment: Olá! Então, nesse sistema, uma pessoa pode cadastrar outras pessoas, e essas outras pessoas cadastrar mais pessoas, formando uma hierarquia. Se a primeira cadastra a segunda, a primeira ganha 10 pontos, e se essa segunda cadastra a uma terceira, a primeira ganha 5 pontos e a segunda ganha 10, então se você cadastrou alguém e ela está "ativa", 10 pontos pra você, e +5 por cada pessoa que você cadastrou, cadastrar outra

Comment: @InácioRégis daí eu queria mostrar quantos pontos a pessoa já tem, somando os 10's da que ela cadastrou, + os 5's que as pessoas que ela cadastrou, e assim vai

Comment: A pontuação vai ficar só no 10 e 5, queria usar como variável dentro do loop

Comment: então é uma consulta dos usuários onde o id é o código da sessão e ela está como "ativa", só que aplicando essa regra do 10 e 5 pontos pra cada usuário cadastrado

Comment: certo, e como vamos saber quem foi cadastrado por quem ou quem cadastrou quem? Como é a estrutura da tabela?

Comment: na tabela de usuários cadastrados, esse "usu_indicador_codigo" é uma chave estrangeira onde mostra o id de quem o cadastrou, e no form de cadastro, ele já insere o id  da session, ou seja, de quem está cadastrando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, se entendi corretamente sua intenção, não precisaria de intervenção do PHP para calcular a pontuação. Podes realizar todo o calculo no lado do banco de dados.
Segue o select correspondente e o link com o exemplo em execução.

**Obs: Eu usei o campo *id* como a primary key, troque para o que você usou.**

Este select retorna todos os dados de todos os usuários com uma coluna com a pontuação ao lado. Para retornar esta coluna é feito um sub-select para retornar a pontuação da indicação direta, somada com o outro sub-select com a indicação do indicado.

```
Select * , (
  (Select (count(id)*10) from esc_usuarios where usu_indicador_codigo = a.id)
  +
  (Select (count(id)*5) from esc_usuarios where usu_indicador_codigo in (
    (Select id from esc_usuarios where usu_indicador_codigo = a.id)
  ))
) pontos
From esc_usuarios a
Where usu_situacao = 'ativo'
```

Caso queira de um usuário especifico insira a regra no where como fez no seu exemplo.

```
AND id = '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "'
```

Segue o link para testes:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/334a44/2

Comment: Perfeito! Justamente o que eu precisava, fico muito agradecido, olhando agora fica bem mais fácil compreender a lógica.

Comment: Rapaz, só tô tendo um probleminha, a query que atualizei com base na sua, não tá contando os ativos que dão 5 pontos, ele só conta se tiver alguem ativo dos que dão 10 pontos. Por exemplo, o usuário 1 cadastrou o usuário 2 (+10), dai o usuário 2 cadastrou o usuário 3(+5), só que se o usuário 2 está inativo, o usuário 1 não recebe os 5 pontos do usuário 3. Vou atualizar o post.

Comment: Ah, se o usuário 3 está inativo, o usuário 1 ainda fica com 15 pontos, quando deveria estar apenas com 10, que seria pelo usuário 2 estar ativo

Comment: quando eu tiro a condição situação = 'ativo', ele conta normal, só que essa condição é muito necessário pro projeto

Comment: nevermind, eu tomei uma garrafa de café e descobri o erro hahahha, obrigado